# Produce a Line Graph in Excel using xlwt in Python

Tags: python, excel-2007, anaconda, spyder

Is it possible to produce an excel line graph using the xlwt module in python? I have not been able to come up with a solution after searching the internet for a while.

I understand there are other modules, but I am wondering if this task is possible with the help of xlwt.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this website [Adding charts to Excel](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).

This is a great website which entails working with Excel using Pandas.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The question is specifically about `xlwt`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question - no, this is one of many xlwt limitations as explained in [python-excel group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/SUcdjlpkOwU).